# GCC gprof complaining GLIBC_2.16 is not found

Tags: embedded-linux, glibc

I have a code running on a PowerPC e500v2 embedded Linux and I want to measure its performance since it is running in an infinite loop. I tried `gcc's gprof` which was simply by adding `-pg` option to gcc. When I run the binary on the target device I get this:

`./main: /lib/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.16 not found (required by ./main)`

I am using ELDK 5.6 toolchain with the default `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` and these flags: `-Wall -lrt -pthread -D_GNU_SOURCE` nothing else. Some article suggested defining `FORTIFY_SOURCE` along with an optimization level but it did not work. I searched for some `gcc`'s feature test macros and tried defining some GLIBC 2.16 specific macros but it did not work.

I faced similar issue with GLIBC 2.17 when I used some structures and functions from `<sched.h>`, adding `_GNU_SOURCE` resolved it. Any idea on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the binary on the target device I get this

Your tool chain targets a version of GLIBC that is newer than what is installed on the target.

This doesn't bite you in non-`pg` compiles only by accident. An "innocent" change to your source can cause the same problem.

You need to upgrade your target to the version of GLIBC which your toolchain actually builds for.